# Using emojis/emoticons in DocPad

Tags: emoji, emoticons, docpad

What would I need to accomplish this? I'm thinking of using the [Phantom Open Emoji](https://github.com/Genshin/PhantomOpenEmoji) set, but I would need to integrate it.

If I can't use this, what could I use in exchange in order to have emojis in my content?

I imagine I would have to make a plugin for this right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of going for a parser I went for a CSS/JS solution to emoticons: https://github.com/JangoSteve/jQuery-CSSEmoticons

Genius concept. :)

Answer (score 1):

Sure, so you could make a plugin that utilises the [`renderDocument` event](http://docpad.org/docs/events#renderdocument) that does a find and replace on `opts.content` for the emoji source and replaces it with the html equivalent.

Something like:

```
opts.content = opts.content.replace(/\:([a-z0-9])\:/i, function(a,b,c,d){
    return 'replacement lookup';
});
```

Comment: Excellent. That really helps. : In a couple of days, maybe today if I manage to figure it out, you'll have a new emoticons plugin. :)

Comment: OK so this is what I've got so far. What's the next step? I appreciate the guidance. :) https://github.com/EduanTech/docpad-plugin-emojis This is a folder inside the `/plugins` folder of course. ;) Also how would I go about testing this? Can I just simply do it correctly and it'll happen or do I have to do the test stuff?

Comment: Sweet, so then find out what the values of a,b,c,d are by doing console.log({a,b,c,d}) - then use them accordingly to return the correct replacement value. For testing, you need to create a `plugin.test.coffee` file as well as a test directory. Check out the plugin writing guide for details on testing: http://docpad.org/docs/plugin-write

Comment: I'm running into problems now... I wasn't able to smoothily setup test stuff. If I do `console.log({a,b,c,d})` I don't get anything, inside a normal DocPad setup, no test stuff. It seems I require a Cakefile, that's what the errors say. Could you please check what I'm missing? https://github.com/EduanTech/docpad-plugin-emojis I'm already at this stage of the testing stuff http://docpad.org/docs/plugin-write#running-the-tests Thanks as always. It's obvious right away that I'm a Node.js newbie. :)

Comment: I want to point out that I completely understand all the logic about it. I mean everything makes sense to me, just not used to working with it so I'm running into problems. :)